# IBM MQueue: setdirectAuth() operation is invalid error

Tags: spring, tomcat, ibm-mq, messaging

I am receiving the following error when I try to access IBM Mqueue from Tomcat.

> com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSMQ1112: The operation
>   for a domain specific object was not valid. The operation
>   'setDirectAuth()' is not valid for type
>   'com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory'.

What could be the possible reasons for this? My code is very long and I cannot post it here.

Answer (score 0):

> What could be the possible reasons for this?

Perhaps because `setDirectAuth()` was called.  It is used to connect to a broker's Real-Time Transport, not a queue.